# Can`t display datetime using Handlebars.js template

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, handlebars.js

everyone. In my ASP.NET MVC project I have a View with a list of objects displayed using Handlebars.js template. Each object has a datetime property, which I want to display or pass somewhere (for example o another view). The problem is that my template shows my datetime data as something like this:

```
/Date(957819600000)/
```

**My model property:**

```
[Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CarManufactureDate { get; set; }
```

**And this is my template:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Model.DTO.CarDTO>
<script id="carListRow" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each cars}}
<tr>
    <td>
        {{CarName}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{CarNickName}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{CarNumber}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{CarManufactureDate}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" data-cars-id="{{Id}}" data-cars-name="{{CarName}}" data-cars-date="{{CarManufactureDate}}" role="button" onclick="carController.deleteCar(this)">@Resources.Resource.deleteString</a>
    </td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Why this is happening and what can I do with this?

Comment: how you build your javascript object from CarDTO ViewModel?

Comment: @Dandy By js object you mean object i'm using for my template? I'm using this. `var encodedCarData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ToList()));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/). Decorate your DateTime property as

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime CarManufactureDate { get; set; }
```

create a class `CustomDateTimeConverter`.

```
class CustomDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public CustomDateTimeConverter()
    {
        base.DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    }
}
```

and in your view you can then use

```
var encodedCarData = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.ToList()));
```

Comment: Well, it's working. Kind of. After adding or changing date this mess is appearing again.

Comment: I think that it's probably datetimepicker's problem. I'm using eonasdan bootstrap datetimepicker and it uses 'DD.MM.YYYY' format. When i'm applying new date everything is normal except when I'm trying to see a result (it's in that creepy format again, but after page reload everything is normal again but still, that`s an issue)